# query for selecting all orders with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a problem where i can't figure out how can i get all orders from tables.
here are my tables

orders :

```
| order_id | user_id |
----------------------
|    3     |    1    |   
----------------------
|    5     |    2    | 
----------------------
|    7     |    4    |
```

order_item :

```
| item_order_id | order_id | item_id |
--------------------------------------
|       1       |    3     |    1    |
--------------------------------------
|       2       |    3     |    2    |
--------------------------------------
|       3       |    5     |    1    |
```

item:

```
| item_id | item_name |   price   |
-----------------------------------
|    1    |  item1    |    100    |
-----------------------------------
|    2    |  item2    |    250    |
-----------------------------------
|    3    |  item3    |    150    |
```

As you see in tables 1 order can have multiple items orders as in example order id 3 had ordered item1 and item2.

My goal is to display all orders in table on my webpage and it should look something like this:

```
    | order id |     orders      |   price   | user_id |
    ----------------------------------------------------
    |     3    |  item1,item2    |    350    |     1   |
    ----------------------------------------------------
    |     5    |      item2      |    250    |     2   |
    ----------------------------------------------------
    |     7    |      item3      |    150    |     4   |
```

so this is my php code:

```
$sql = "SELECT MAX(order_id) FROM orders";
         $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);        
        $count =  $result['MAX(order_id)'];
        for($i = 1;$i<$count;$i++){


            $sql = "SELECT o.order_id, u.username, i.item_name FROM orders o 
            JOIN order_item oi ON oi.order_id=o.order_id
            JOIN users u on u.user_id=o.user_id
            JOIN item i ON i.item_id=oi.item_id WHERE o.order_id = $i";

    $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){

        $order_id =  $result['order_id'];
        $item =  $result['item_name'];
        $username =  $result['username'];    
        echo   "<td style='border-top:1px solid #5C1916;'>$order_id  </td>
        <td style='border-top:1px solid #5C1916;'>$item  </td>
        <td style='border-top:1px solid #5C1916;'>   $username </td>
        </tr>"  ;

    }}
```

Problem is that when my `$i` gets to lets say 3, that user has 2 ordered items and it shows those items in two separated rows and i want it to be just like on table above.Does anyone have idea how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sample ther is not order_ite for order id = 1
so if you need  just matching rows  then use inner join

```
select a.order_id , group_concat(c.item_name), sum( c.price), a.user_id 
from  orders a 
inner  join  order_item b on a.order_id = b.order_id 
inner join item c on c.item_id = b.item_id 
group by  a.order_id
```

otherwise use left join

```
select a.order_id , group_concat(c.item_name), sum( c.price), a.user_id 
from  orders a 
left  join  order_item b on a.order_id = b.order_id 
inner join item c on c.item_id = b.item_id 
group by  a.order_id
```

Comment: Thanks alot,i was looking for this for a long time,didn't know about `group_concat()` function, that one solved it